# Generate a dynamic modal/dialog within a datatable in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a datatable, with so many columns. I want to display only a few columns in the datatable, and show the rest of the data on a modal/dialog when user clicks on the "More" link in the row.

Below is my template.

```
<v-data-table :headers="tableHeaders" :items="creditCardTransactions">
    <template v-slot:item.moreInfo="{ item }">
        <v-icon @click.stop="$set(dialogNote, item.id, true)">mdi-information</v-icon>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialogNote[item.id]" :key="item.id">
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title>
                    <span>More Info</span>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-simple-table>
                        <template v-slot:default>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="25%">Column A</th>
                                <td>{{ item.ColumnA }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="25%">Column B</th>
                                <td>{{ item.ColumnB }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </template>
                    </v-simple-table>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn color="primary" @click.stop="$set(dialogNote, item.id, false)">Close</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I have `dialogNote` as object:

```
public dialogNote: object = {};
```

The problem is, this is generating a modal/dialog for each of the row on the datatable, which means thouthands of extra line of HTML code on the page, which means slow page.

Question is, how can I just have one modal/dialog and reuse it? For example, there will be just one modal on the page, and when "More" button is clicked on the row, the content of the modal changes reflecting that particular row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create v-dialog out of the v-data-table, and in the table just add method to your button, that will pass data table item to your dialog.
So:

1. Add new data, and replace the dialog v-model with that, for example `v-model="selectedDialogNote"`
2. Add new method that will pass data-table item to the  `selectedDialogNote`
3. Move dialog out of the table and add the method to the button in table

So there will be only one dialog and big table with buttons that have one method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-data-table>
... contents
  <v-btn @click="showDialog(item)">Show More</v-btn>
</v-data-table>

<v-dialog v-model="show">
... dialog content
... currentDialogItem
</v-dialog>

//scripts
export default {
  data(){
    return { 
       show: false,
       currentDialogItem: {}
    }
  },
  methods:{
    showDialog(item){
      this.show = true;
      this.currentDialogItem = item;
    }
  }
}
```